# Simba JDBC driver For Cloud Spanner used with Spark JDBC DataFrame reader

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

I am using the JDBC driver of Simba Technologies Inc to get connected with the Google cloud spanner. It is running as expected with Java.sql. when, I tried to use the simba JDBC driver with the Spark's JDBC reader in order to read query output as DataFrame but, it is giving wrong output.

Here is my **spanner table**:

```
UserID  UserName
1   Vaijnath
2   Ganesh
3   Rahul
```

**MetaData:**
UserID(String)
UserName(String)

I am executing **Query** as: SELECT * FROM users

This query fetch correct data when I use Simba JDBC driver with Java Sql, but it fails to fetch data When I use it with Spark SQL's JDBC reader.

It returns the DataFrame as

```
+------+--------+
|UserID|UserName|
+------+--------+
|UserID|UserName|
|UserID|UserName|
|UserID|UserName|
+------+--------+
```

As we can see, it is returning correct metadata and number of rows but, row contains the column names.

Here is the code I am using:

```
import java.util.Properties
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, SparkSession}

object  spannerIn {
    val sparkSession =SparkSession
            .builder()
            .appName("Spark SQL basic example").master("local")
            .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "file:///tmp")
            .config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", 1)
            .getOrCreate()

    val properties =new Properties()
    properties.setProperty("user", "")
    properties.setProperty("password", "")
    properties.setProperty("driver", "com.simba.cloudspanner.core.jdbc42.CloudSpanner42Driver")

    val connectionURL="jdbc:cloudspanner://localhost;Project=abc;Instance=pqr;Database=xyz;PvtKeyPath=FilePath"
    val selectQuery="(select * from users)"
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
            val df = createJdbcDataframe()
            df.show()
    }
    def createJdbcDataframe(): DataFrame = {
    sparkSession.read.jdbc(connectionURL, selectQuery, properties)
    }
}
```

My question is, can I Use the Simba JDBC Driver with Spark?
If Yes, then what extra things I need to add.
Any help Appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This occurs because Spark by default quote all identifiers using a double quote ("), meaning the following query is being generated:

```
SELECT "UserID", "UserName" FROM USERS
```

This is interpreted by Cloud Spanner as selecting two fixed strings. It's basically the same as this in most other databases:

```
SELECT 'UserID', 'UserName' FROM USERS
```

Google Cloud Spanner uses backticks (`) for quoting identifiers, and expects this:

```
SELECT `UserID`, `UserName` FROM USERS
```

To fix this, you need to register a specific JDBC dialect for Google Cloud Spanner and register the backtick for quoting like this:

```
    Class.forName("nl.topicus.jdbc.CloudSpannerDriver");
    SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("Java Spark SQL basic example")
                .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value").master("local").getOrCreate();
    String sparkURL = "jdbc:cloudspanner://localhost;Project=project-id;Instance=instance-id;Database=db;PvtKeyPath=pathToKeyFile.json";
    JdbcDialects.registerDialect(new JdbcDialect()
    {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public boolean canHandle(String url)
        {
            return url.toLowerCase().startsWith("jdbc:cloudspanner:");
        }

        @Override
        public String quoteIdentifier(String column)
        {
            return "`" + column + "`";
        }
    });
    Dataset<Row> dataset = spark.read().jdbc(sparkURL, "ACCOUNT", new Properties());
    dataset.show();
```

Please note that I have not tested the above with the Simba driver, but only with this driver: https://github.com/olavloite/spanner-jdbc
I guess it should work with the Simba driver as well.